# página de carga antes de redirigir a otra

Tags: php

Buenas, necesito hacer una página que se mostrará durante dos segundos antes de redirigir al usuario a la página final. Tengo este código que, obviamente no funciona:

```
<?php
     sleep(2);
     header('location:v_index.php');
?>
```

Este script lo tengo incrustado en la página que se tiene que ver entre la inicial y la final.

Lo que me ocurre es que en vez de cargar esta página la función sleep() se ejecuta desde la primera página y se redirecciona directamente a la final sin pasar por la página de carga

De que manera podría hacerlo?

gracias de antemano

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que quieres hacer es que se muestre tu página (su contenido) unos **N** segundos y luego de eso se envie al visitante a donde realmente interactuara.

Para ello te sugiero lo siguiente (estructura ejemplo):

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
  // todo tu proceso en PHP para armar lo que mostraras en HTML
?>
<script>
// En la siguiente línea el parámetro final la unidad son milisegundos; en el ejemplo se indica esperar 3 segundos-
setTimeout(function(){ window.location="<?= 'v_index.php' ?>"; }, 3000); // Aquí es donde se "redirecciona" luego de trancurridos los N segundos que indiques
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que necesitas es re-direccionamiento, hay varias formas de lograr tu objetivo ( como siempre sucede en el mundo de la programación hay mas de una solución a un mismo problema ). Vamos a ello

primero veamos el que estas usando:

```
    <?php
     sleep(2);
     header('location:v_index.php');
?>
```

El fallo aqui es que probablemente no tengas la pagina de destino en el lugar el cual estas indicando. siendo mas claros, donde dice 'Location:' luego de los : indicas la pagina, iniciando por la ruta. Si la pagina esta en la misma ruta donde esta tu pagina index.php entonces debes poner el nombre del archivo iniciando con un espacio ejemplo: 'Location: v_index.php'

Sin embargo si la pagina esta dentro de un folder dentro de la ruta de tu index.php debes indicarlo usando '/' y quedaria asi:
'Location: /folder/v_index.php'

asi que tu codigo seria:

```
    <?php
         header('location: v_index.php');
?>
```

o este

```
 <?php
     sleep(2);
     header('location: /folder/v_index.php');
?>
```